# Onsen UI for Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017, onsen-ui, apache-cordova

My question is about how can I use Onsen UI in visual studio 2017? I need to use this framework to build an app with Apache Cordova.

Answer (score 0):

There's no template for Visual Studio 2017. 
The next best option is to make a blank Apache Cordova App and add the Onsen UI template manually.

As said on another forum, I haven't personally tried out this method.